# Can't connect to local server on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, poco-libraries

I have a weird problem with my server application written in C++ using POCO libraries. It worked fine and just stopped working few days ago. Even using the exe from 2 weeks ago it doesn't work.

The problem is, I can't connect to the server through localhost, but other people from outside my network can connect without any problem...

I've tested it on other computers and it's the same, except for one computer. 
The problem exists only on Windows. I've tested in on Linux and it worked fine.

The problem also reproduces on POCO tutorial's code from http://pocoproject.org/slides/200-Network.pdf:

```
#include "Poco/Net/ServerSocket.h"
#include "Poco/Net/StreamSocket.h"
#include "Poco/Net/SocketStream.h"
#include "Poco/Net/SocketAddress.h"
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Poco::Net::ServerSocket srv(8080); // does bind + listen
    for (;;)
    {
        Poco::Net::StreamSocket ss = srv.acceptConnection();
        Poco::Net::SocketStream str(ss);
        str << "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n"
        "Content-Type: text/html\r\n"
        "\r\n"
        "<html><head><title>My 1st Web Server</title></head>"
        "<body><h1>Hello, world!</h1></body></html>"
        << std::flush;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Entering 127.0.0.1:8080 in Chrome results in ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED.
http://www.canyouseeme.org/ reports that it can see my service on port 8080.

Other applications (not using POCO I guesss?) work fine.

I have absolutely no idea what is the cause of this problem...
I would be grateful for any advices.

Comment: Looks like a firewall, a spyware (spam-proxy) or a dll-hell problem. Have you tried to start on another port? maybe some service is using this port but not with http? Can you test it with net cat? download net cat and start nc -lp8080 ans another instance nc 127.0.0.1 8080. Do they connect?

Comment: Starting on another port doesn't solve the problem. No other service is using this port neither. Yes, they connect: http://screenshooter.net/102449625/xdwtuqk

Comment: Might the problem have been introduced by this month's Windows updates?

Comment: That was my first suspicion, although I have created a virtual machine with clean windows 7 installation, and the problem still occurs.

Comment: @ValentinHeinitz I dont think it's dll-hell problem neither. I've linked the server against static libraries (exe relies only on kernel32, advapi32, ihlpapi and ws2_32) and the problem still occurs.

Comment: How can canyouseeme open your local port? Have you enabled port forwarding in your router or is the machine connected directly to Internet? What happens, if you netcat this port? Does it connects? I mean is it TCP or HTTP problem? If not, then probably firewall only fakes open port to external machines for preventing port scanning. As another idea, could you start your application in dependency walker's profiling? Are there any unexpected fails in DLL's loadings? Can you enable additional logs in POCO or use the debugger?

Comment: All port are forwarded to my computer. On the example code the netcat connects to the port and retrieves the hello world. But on the actual application it doesnt connect. When I start it under the dependency walker's profiling it crashes, and I can't attach the debugger to it.  Here's the output: http://pastebin.com/Bc5MHKKL

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your example. It looks like normal behaviour. If it used to work, than it's rather not normal. Could it be, You've updated Chrome or tested if before with some older browser?

In that example the server is sending the data and closes the connection instantly. I assume, there should be a command in POCO  to terminate the connection in any more graceful way.

The example seems to demonstrate very simple, but not protocol conform server response. Try using HTTPRequestHandlerFactory. This way the server seems not to terminate the connection after each request.

Firefox shows very short **"Hello World!"** and then "Connection aborted"

`ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED` in Chrome means probably also that the server unexpectedly closed the connection.

curl shows in most cases:

```
C:\bin>curl.exe http://localhost:8080
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection was reset
```

But in some rare cases:

```
C:\bin>curl.exe http://localhost:8080
<html><head><title>My 1st Web Server</title></head><body><h1>Hello, world!</h1></body></html>

curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection was reset
```

After I've added a `Sleep(100)` after `flush` the html content is always displayed before `Recv failure`. So depending on timing the content is displayed or not by the browser.

May be there is the hint for the different behaviour on linux:

```
void HTTPServerConnection::onServerStopped(const bool& abortCurrent)
{
    _stopped = true;
    if (abortCurrent)
    {
        try
        {
            // Note: On Windows, select() will not return if one of its socket is being
            // shut down. Therefore we have to call close(), which works better.
            // On other platforms, we do the more graceful thing.
#if defined(_WIN32)
            socket().close();
#else
            socket().shutdown();
```

Comment: Then why this error only occurs inside the local network and there is no problem from the outside? Also, my full code which does not close the connection after a while still doesn't work.

Comment: So, the connection from outside works? You'have mentioned only canyouseeme.org, which can't really test HTTP stack. Can you really connect with a browser from another computer? Could you try `curl.exe -v` on local computer? What is the output?

Comment: I've mentioned that "other people from outside my network can connect without any problem" :) Yes, accessing my.ip.address:8080 in browser from outside works like a charm.  Curl output: http://pastebin.com/ZHjsGwby

Comment: Strange, today my server application works... I didnt change anything though.